# How to Read Multiple Json in java

Tags: java, json

By using below code i get

```
{"User_id":"test123","Password":"test225"}{"User_id":"test122","Password":"asds"}
```

format of json which is invalid

Actually i want below format of json but i unable to create 
       **

### [{ "User_id": "test123", "Password": "test225" }, { "User_id": "test122", "Password": "asds" }]

**

Here is my json create code

```
 String Filename="json_log_text";
       JSONObject jobject=new JSONObject();
       jobject.put("User_id",jTextField1.getText());
       jobject.put("Password",jPasswordField1.getText());

       FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(("D:\\file store\\"+Filename+".txt"),true);
       writer.write(jobject.toJSONString());
       writer.flush();
```

Comment: JSON is invalid.

Comment: i added my json writing code also

Comment: You keep appending JSON arrays to the same file?

Comment: yes @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: Well, then you'll need a strategy to separate them again later. Probably writing each on a new line and afterwards parsing line by line is the easiest approach.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen : thank you for suggestion but im not understand its bounce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i Got solution For read Multiple read json at time pasting code for future help to someone, For this i'm use **json-simple-1.1.1.jar**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileWriter;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream.*;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
```

**for json write**

```
String Filename="json_log_text";
       JSONObject jobject=new JSONObject();
       JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray();
       jobject.put("User_id",jTextField1.getText());
       jobject.put("Password",jPasswordField1.getText());
       jarray.add(jobject);

   FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(("D:\\file store\\"+Filename+".txt"),true);
   writer.write(jobject.toJSONString());
   writer.flush();
```

**Json Read**

```
 String user_id=jTextField1.getText();
  String Password=jPasswordField1.getText();

              String Filename1="json_log_text_parse";
           JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();



            JSONObject jobject1=new JSONObject();
           JSONArray jarray1=new JSONArray();
            jobject1.put("User_id",jTextField1.getText());
       jobject1.put("Password",jPasswordField1.getText());
       jarray1.add(jobject1);
       FileWriter writer1 =new FileWriter(Filename,true);
       BufferedWriter bf2=new BufferedWriter(writer1);
       PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(bf2);

       pw=new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\file store\\"+Filename1+".txt"),true));



              for (Object o:jarray1)
           {

               JSONObject jsonobject=(JSONObject) o;


                user_id=(String) jsonobject.get("User_id");
               pw.print("User_id:"+user_id+"\n");


              Password=(String) jsonobject.get("Password");
               pw.print("Password:"+Password+"\n");



           }

                pw.println();
                pw .close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of `[{"User_id":"ss","Password":"ssss"}] [{"User_id":"abc","Password":"ss"}] [{"User_id":"jk","Password":"aa"}]` does not match any [JSON data types](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp).

Try convert it to an array:

```
[{"User_id":"ss","Password":"ssss"},{"User_id":"abc","Password":"ss"},{"User_id":"jk","Password":"aa"}]
```